# Match object properties for two ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I am using two `ng-repeat`s and matching properties with `ng-if`. The first `ng-repeat` loops over nearly 250 objects with an object array like:

```
[{
  "Title": "First1 Last1",
  "FirstName": "First1",
  "LastName": "Last1",
  "ID": 29
}, {
  "Title": "First2 Last2",
  "FirstName": "First2",
  "LastName": "Last2",
  "ID": 25
}]
```

The second `ng-repeat` loops over nearly 4600 objects in an object array similar to:

```
[{
  "ParentUserLink": {
    "ID": 25
  },
  "Title": "USER2",
  "InitialPassword": "Already Received",
}, {
  "ParentUserLink": {
    "ID": 29
  },
  "Title": "USER1",
  "InitialPassword": "Asdf1234",
}, {
  "ParentUserLink": {
    "ID": 25
  },
  "Title": "USER2",
  "InitialPassword": "Already Received",
}, {
  "ParentUserLink": {
    "ID": 25
  },
  "Title": "USER2",
  "InitialPassword": "Already Received",
}]
```

Using `ng-repeat="app in apps" ng-if="app.ParentUserLink.ID == user.ID"` allows me to show applications when they belong to the correct user. However this can take several minutes to load and will often crash the browser. What would be a more efficient way of doing this?

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" id="pagebreak">
  <div class="ProfileSheet">
    <h3 class="heading" style="border-top: 3px solid #707070;">User Profile</h3>
    <table id="Profile" style="border-top: 3px solid #707070;">
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <h3 class="heading">User Applications</h3>
    <div style="border:3px solid #707070; padding-right:12px;">
      <h4 style="padding-left:5px;">User Applications</h4>
      <table id="Apps">
        <tr id="AppsHeading">
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Initial Password</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="app in apps" ng-if="app.ParentUserLink.ID == user.ID">
          <td>{{app.Title}}</td>
          <td>{{app.InitialPassword}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the relationship for user-to-application? Is it one-to-one? one-to-many? many-to-many?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts One user can have many applications.

Comment: But can multiple users have the same application as well?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes.

Comment: Could you include a bit of your angular controller code so that an answer can modify what you currently have rather than writing from scratch? Not the full source, just the bones of how you're populating the `$scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter in the `ng-repeat` expression:

```
̵<̵t̵r̵ ̵n̵g̵-̵r̵e̵p̵e̵a̵t̵=̵"̵a̵p̵p̵ ̵i̵n̵ ̵a̵p̵p̵s̵"̵ ̵n̵g̵-̵i̵f̵=̵"̵a̵p̵p̵.̵P̵a̵r̵e̵n̵t̵U̵s̵e̵r̵L̵i̵n̵k̵.̵I̵D̵ ̵=̵=̵ ̵u̵s̵e̵r̵.̵I̵D̵"̵>̵
<tr ng-repeat="app in apps | filter : idFilter(user.ID)">
  <td>{{app.Title}}</td>
  <td>{{app.InitialPassword}}</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.idFilter = function(id) {
    return filter;
    function filter(value, index, array) {
         return value.ParentUserLink.ID == id;
    }
};
```

This avoids using the `ng-if` directive with its associated child scope and watchers.

Comment: It is cleaner, but does it improve the runtime and prevent his crashes? If it does do you know why?

Comment: It avoids using the `ng-if` directive with its associated child scope and watchers. In this case it avoids 250 * 4600 `ng-if` directives.

Comment: This worked for me and loads after a couple seconds! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to significantly improve the runtime would be to only iterate over your 4600 object list once in the controller and use that to power the view.  Just off the top of my head one strategy is:

1. Create an empty array
2. iterate over objects
3. check the index for the given user id (i.e. if ID = 29 then check `array[29]`)
4. If the index is empty, add an array with the current object, else push the current object to the array in that index

Now in your view you can change your `ng-repeat` to use the `array[ID]` as the array to iterate over.

That is just one strategy and it most likely isn't the optimal solution, but it should improve the runtime significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates 250 * 4600 times. You can simply reduce it upto 250 + 4600.

controller:

```
var obj = {};
apps.forEach((app) => {
    obj[app.ParentUserLink.ID] = obj[app.ParentUserLink.ID] || [];
    obj[app.ParentUserLink.ID].push(app);
});
```

html:

```
....ng-repeat="user in users"
    ....ng-repeat"app in obj[user.id] || []"
```